# How to process multi-row result in a custom way?

Tags: java, jdbc, java-8, spring-jdbc

For now I have method body of which looks like this:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(queryJoiningTwoTables, (rs, rowNum) -> {
    final long id= rs.getLong("id");
    MyObject obj = jobStatusBunchMap.get(id);
    if (obj== null) {
        OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = rs.getObject("creation_timestamp", OffsetDateTime.class);
        ...
        obj = new MyObject (offsetDateTime ...);
        map.put(id, obj );
    }
    String jobId = rs.getString("job_id");
    obj.getJobIds().add(jobId);
    return null;
});
return map.values();
```

Looks like I use API in improper way.

Is there better method to achieve the same ?

**P.S.**

I tried to use `jdbcTemplate#queryForRowSet` but at this case `rs.getObject("creation_timestamp", OffsetDateTime.class)` throws exception that it is not supported operation.

Comment: 1. It is not a query time - business entity creation time. 2 I have 1-M relation between entities and I want to create in memory objects using single sql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options to map the results using jdbcTemplate, including yours.
Maybe this will help you to understand it better:

```
public List<Action> findAllActions() {
    final String selectStatement = "SELECT id,name FROM Actions"; // or your query
    try {

        return jdbcTemplate.query(selectStatement,(resultSet, rowNum) -> {

            int actionId = resultSet.getInt("id");
            String actionName = resultSet.getString("name");

            Action action = new Action();
            action.setId(actionId);
            action.setName(actionName);

            return action;
        });

    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Get all actions - empty set", e);
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Without lambda expressions you could use jdbcTemplate query like  this:

```
public List<Action> findAllActions() {
    final String selectStatement = "SELECT id,name FROM Actions"; // or your query
    try {

        return jdbcTemplate.query(selectStatement, getActionRowMapper());

    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Get all actions - empty set", e);
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
private RowMapper<Action> getActionRowMapper() {
    return (resultSet, rowNum) -> {

        int actionId = resultSet.getInt("id");
        String actionName = resultSet.getString("name");

        return action;
    };
}
```

As you can see, the second parameter of jdbcTemplate.query method takes a `RowMapper<Action>` type but is hidden using lambdas expressions. This option is "restricting" you from making anything else besides mapping the resultSet for every row and return the result. The final result will be eventually a `List` of actions.

The second option is using a `ResultSetExtractor` which will let you to loop through the result set and gives you more flexibility. The query will be the same, just the second parameter of jdbcTemplate.query method will be changed. And for this, I would personally implement the `ResultSetExtractor` and override the **extractData** method, or you can do the same as above if you don't need anything else just to map the results

```
public List<Group> findGroups() {
    final String selectStatement = "SELECT stud.id, stud.name, gr.id, gr.name FROM student stud INNER JOIN group gr ON gr.id=stud.group_id ORDER BY stud.id"; // or your query
    try {

        return jdbcTemplate.query(selectStatement, new GroupExtractor() );

    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Get all groups - empty set", e);
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}


public class GroupExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor<List<Group>> {
@Override
public List<Group> extractData(ResultSet resultSet) {
    Map<Group, List<Student>> studentsGroup= new HashMap<>();
    List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
          int studentId = resultSet.getInt("stud.id");
            String studentName = resultSet.getString("stud.name");
            int groupId = resultSet.getInt("gr.id");
            String groupName = resultSet.getString("gr.name");

            Group group = createGroup(groupId, groupName);
            Student student = createStudent(studentId, studentName);

            studentsGroup.putIfAbsent(group, new ArrayList<>());
            studentsGroup.get(group).add(student);

        }

        studentsGroup.forEach((group,students) ->{
            group.setStudents(students);
            groups.add(group);
        }

        return groups;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.info("An error occured during extracting data", e);
    }
    return actions;
 }

private Student createStudent(String studentId, String studentName)
{
  Student student=new Student();
  student.setId(studentId);
  student.setName(studentName);
  return student;
}

//idem for createGroup
}
```

Comment: Looks like you misunderstood my question. The problem that my select returns 100(for example) rows but I want to get less than 100 (let say 20 ) objects because it is query with join

Comment: Then it's better to use ["LIMIT"](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx) clause from mysql inside your SQL query. (Use MySQL clauses everytime you have the oportunity instead of java code. Let the MySQL do the "hardwork" )

Comment: you don't get me at all. Let say I have 5 rows in a table GROUP and  each group has 20 corresponding rows in the STUDENT table. If execute query which joins 2 tables we get 100 rows. But I want to get a result of 5 groups objects with filled students collection for each group

Comment: Please look at the last code snippet in my answer (I've modified it) and tell me if that is what you need to know (and in that case, please don't forget to override the equals() and hashCode() methods inside Group and Student classes)

Comment: Yes, it is what I was looking for